# About the method of proving a set is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is:

> Prove or disprove:
>
> > The real numbers with decimal representation consisting of all $1$'s is countable.

I received the answer like this

$$
\begin{matrix}
1&1.1&1.11&1.111&\cdots \\
11&11.1&11.11&11.111&\cdots \\
111&111.1&111.11&111.11&\cdots \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
\end{matrix}
$$

and count like, $1,\ 1.1,\ 11,\ 1.11,\ 11.1,\ 111,\dots$

My question is about this method, there is one point I can't understand.

To be specific, for example:

> Prove or disprove:
>
> > The real numbers with decimal representations of all $1$'s or $2$'s is countable.

I know this set is not countable, but I can count like this.

$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Length}\\
1&1&2\\
2&1.1&1.2&2.1&2.2\\
3&1.11&1.12&1.21&1.22&2.11&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
\end{matrix}
$$

and count like $1,\ 2,\ 1.1,\ 1.2,\ 2.1,\ 2.2,\ 1.11,\ 1.12 \dots$
so it's countable?

However, use the
$$
r_1=r_{10}.r_{11}r_{12}\dots\\
r_2=r_{20}.r_{21}r_{22}\dots\\
\vdots
$$
take $s=s_0.s_1s_2\dots$where $s_i=\begin{cases}1,&\text{ if }r_{ii}\neq 1\\2,&\text{ if }r_{ii}=1\end{cases}$

In my case, $r_1=1,\ r_2=2,\ r_3=1.1,\ \dots$
then say $s = 2.2$ but $2.2$ will be counted?

Where am I wrong?

---

Some may say that $s$ should be take as $2.21111111\dots$, because $s_2,s_3,s_4\dots$should not be $0$. And $2.21111111\dots$ will not be counted

But how about the first question? I can say $1.111111\dots$ will not be counted?

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overlooking the fact that the set of real numbers with decimal expansion consisting of both $1$s and $2$s has (uncountably) many infinitely long members, all distinct. Among the reals that use only $1$, there is only one, $1.111\dotsc$, and that represents a rational as do all the finite ones. However, for any subset $X$ of the integers, there is a real $r_X = 1.d_1 d_2 d_3\dotsc$ corresponding to it, where for each $i$, $d_{i+1} = 1$ if $i\in X$ and $d_{i+1} = 2$ if $i\notin X$. So there are as many of these reals as there are subsets of $\Bbb N$ — uncountably many.